# Getting error in payment option in Spree Commerc with Balanced Payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, balanced-payments

I am using Spree Commerce with balance payment as a payment gateway and getting error on payment page

```
Card Number*: 4111 1111 1111 1111
Expiration*: 02 /2014
Card Code*: 123
```

Error: 
There was a problem with your payment information. Please check your information and try again.

> 1 error prohibited this record from being saved:

```
There were problems with the following fields:
Card stored
```

If any one have solution for this do share with me......

Comment: Sam, do you know your marketplace URI? You can check your logs on the dashboard by logging in to https://dashboard.balancedpayments.com/

Comment: yes here is my marketplace URI: `/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP3y5fd17CDlUFe1aXxRgY5W` , I have forked 2-1-stable branch of spree, I think it is causing issues. Please suggest what should how can recover from that error.